# How to fix Error executing process Utility 'pg_restore' not found in client home '/usr/lib' (/usr/lib)?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, pg-restore

I want to restore database backup and I'm using ubuntu 20.04, dbeaver and postgresql 12.

When I want to add `Local client` then `Add home` I get `permission denied error`

[image]

running command `which psql` resulting in `/usr/bin/psql`.

I know that the postgresql path is `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin`, but the problem is that I can't access the psql path with dbeaver.

I also granted all permissions for dbeaver.[image]

here is the actual error i get:

[image]

is there any way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That indicates that you got strange permissions set on the `/usr` directory. Allow the user that started DBeaver "read" and "execute" on that directory.

On correctly installed Linux machines, the permissions should be set like this:

```
> ls -ld /usr
drwxr-xr-x. 39 root root 4096 Jan 11 10:28 /usr
```

You can set them like that with

```
chmod 0755 /usr
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz, I did it using commad line and psql. and it worked.